# Magento compare products

Tags: magento

I need to modify magento compare products , so that it display products according to category ?
i need to modify data which appear in this url-> 
/magento/index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/

Answer (score 0):

you will have to alter

```
    app/design/frontend/default/template/default/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml
```

or the file in the theme you use to override that

Comment: what exactly i need to do to display product ordering by their congeries ?